What is the Literature SE policy for self-answered questions?
I had some strong rejection to this question and self-answer of mine:
I am looking for a book from a spanish academic researcher on the history of paper (or of books)
The answer may look easy, but I can assure you it was not easy at all.
Nonetheless, from a 2017 question in the meta regarding the eligibility of self-answers on questions, the most voted answer is a strong "There's absolutely nothing wrong with it, and it's actually encouraged."
I therefore wonder what is the official policy, 7 years later.

There's no policy against self-answered questions, and attempts to create one have been rebuffed. The general policy is, as you already saw, that Q&A from the same poster is not a problem.

I suspect the backlash against your specific Q&A may have been based on a misunderstanding. We often see inexperienced users posting updates to their query (e.g. providing further details on an ID question) as answers when they should have been edits to the question. People unfamiliar with the SE system may not know that they can edit their posts, or may think that all further updates should appear as posts in a thread, forum-style. I'm guessing Matt Thrower assumed you were one of those rather than doing a genuine self-answered Q&A, and that's why he deleted your original answer and edited it into your question.
There's another problem too: as it stands, your question is not very good. It's very short, almost a one-liner, and includes very little information about the book you're looking for. If you hadn't posted an answer as the OP, would anyone else have been able to find the book or, having found it, to be sure it's the one you wanted? Ideally, an ID question should have a single correct answer, and its correctness (and the incorrectness of others) should be clear from the OP's description. The comments also indicate that at least one user feels the question may be off-topic, as it concerns a history book rather than a piece of literature. (But if it's a book about the history of literature, that's another way of being on-topic.)
All of the above has nothing to do with you having self-answered. If you want to get a better reception, I suggest editing your question to include a bit more detail about what you were looking for (obviously not any detail that shows you've already found it, just enough to let it stand as a reasonable-quality ID question) and maybe to clarify the book's relevance to literature.
